# PHP SQL Query results issue with dates

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem with the code below.

For some reason it displays only dates from October, November and December.

The dates have the same format... see below:

```
DATE            RESULT

2013-02-01      Does Not Display
2013-03-01      Does Not Display
2013-04-01      Does Not Display
2013-05-01      Does Not Display
2013-06-01      Does Not Display
2013-07-01      Does Not Display
2013-08-01      Does Not Display
2013-09-01      Does Not Display
2013-10-01      Displays OK
2013-11-01      Displays OK
2013-12-01      Displays OK
```

Here is the query code:

```
$events = array();
$query = "SELECT title, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') AS date FROM mytable WHERE user_id = '$session_user_id' AND date LIKE '$year-$month%' AND active = 1";
$result = mysql_query($query,$db_link) or die('cannot get results!');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$events[$row['date']][] = $row;

}
```

Anyone have any ideas of why this could be happening?

Comment: Let me guess... `$year = 2013` and `$month = 1`?  Think about what will be the rendered query: `date LIKE '2013-1%'`.

Comment: The PHP code is completely irrelevant here. What does the generated SQL code look like?

Comment: check your $month variable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @mellamokb's comment. Instead of using `LIKE` use `BETWEEN`. This also makes the query faster.

```
$query = "SELECT title, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') AS date FROM mytable WHERE user_id = '$session_user_id' AND date BETWEEN '$year-$month-1' AND '" . date("Y-m-t", strtotime("$year-$month-1")) . "' AND active = 1";
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're using month = 1. You're getting 10, 11 and 12 only, since they are the only months that start with 1.